# Converting Crystal report to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, crystal-reports

is there any facility available in crystal report(c# .net) to change the font to some other language? if no, how to convert crystal report to pdf format?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportOptions objExOpt;

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (object)getReportDocument();
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    // Get the report document
       ReportDocument repDoc = getReportDocument();

    repDoc.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    repDoc.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
    DiskFileDestinationOptions objDiskOpt = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
    objDiskOpt.DiskFileName = @"c:\crystal report\TFA.pdf";
    repDoc.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = objDiskOpt;
    repDoc.Export();
 }

private ReportDocument getReportDocument()
{
  // File Path for Crystal Report
  string repFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt");
  // Declare a new Crystal Report Document object
  // and the report file into the report document
  ReportDocument repDoc = new ReportDocument();

  repDoc.Load(repFilePath);

  // Set the datasource by getting the dataset from business
  // layer and
 // In our case business layer is getCustomerData function
 return repDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ReportObject objReport in rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section3"].ReportObjects)
{
   FieldObject objField = (FieldObject)objReport;
   objField.ApplyFont(new Font("Arial", 8.25F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))));
}
```

For PDF, See following:

- [Create PDF from Crystal Report](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4946-Create-pdf-from-crystal-report.aspx)
- [Crystal reports export](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-pdf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportDocument reportobj = //Add code to return valid report document from a crystal report 
if (reportobj != null)
{
    //Export to PDF
    ((ReportDocument)reportobj).ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, file);
    //Open using default app for PDF docs
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :
first  create instance of Crystal report, and you can simply Call Export To disk

```
  RtpDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\report.pdf")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.