# how to email crystal report in pdf form

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am new here and this is my first post, if there is any mistake pardon me and do let me know I'l correct it.
My question is I need to email crystal report to a particular recipient's email address which will also be included in crystal report, and that crystal report needs to be in PDF format, is this possible, if yes then can you please elaborate the procedure how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: The answers provided should guide you to converting into pdf, but for the email part to work, some further configurations are needed. Have you thought on what SMTP server to use for sending emails, for example?

Answer (score 3):

```
string pdfFile = "c:\\CrytalReport.pdf";

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFile;
            CrExportOptions = ReportDocument .ExportOptions;//Report document  object has to be given here
            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            ReportDocument .Export();

            sendmail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    private void sendmail()
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            Msg.To = "to Address";
            Msg.From = "From Address";
            Msg.Subject = "Crystal Report Attachment ";
            Msg.Body = "Crystal Report Attachment ";
            Msg.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(pdfFile));
           // System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(Msg);

            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "you mail domain";
            //SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0,"127.0.0.1");

            SmtpMail.Send(Msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Don't forget add these DLL's

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
```

Comment: If I am not wrong in this crystal report has already been converted to PDF, if thats correct can you tell how to covert RPT file  to PDF.

Comment: you can see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521702/converting-crystal-report-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CrystalReport
/// </summary>
'public class CrystalReport
{

    private void SetDBLogOnInfo(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument objectReportDocument, TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo)
    {

        Tables Tbl = objectReportDocument.Database.Tables;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table TmpTbl in Tbl)
        {

            tableLogonInfo = TmpTbl.LogOnInfo;

            tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;

            TmpTbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
        }
    }

    public ReportDocument CrystalLogon(String pReportPath, ConnectionInfo objConnInfo, ref TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo)
    {

        ReportDocument objReportDoc = new ReportDocument();

        objReportDoc.Load(pReportPath);

        SetDBLogOnInfo(objConnInfo, objReportDoc, tableLogonInfo);

        return objReportDoc;

    }

    public string[] GetCampaignConn()
    {
        //string server, database, userid, password;
        string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Connection String"];
        string[] strArray = strConn.Split(';');

        string[] strOutput = new string[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] strObject = strArray[i].Split('=');

            if (strObject[0] == "Data Source")
            {
                strOutput[0] = strObject[1];
            }
            else if (strObject[0] == "Initial Catalog")
            {
                strOutput[1] = strObject[1];
            }
            else if (strObject[0] == "User ID")
            {
                strOutput[2] = strObject[1];
            }
            else if (strObject[0] == "Password")
            {
                strOutput[3] = strObject[1];
            }
        }

        return strOutput;
    }
}`
```

use above method you will problem will resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetReportDataSource(string sCarrierID)
    {
        try
        {
            CrystalReport objCrystalReport = new CrystalReport();

            //ReportDocument objReportDoc = new ReportDocument();

            ConnectionInfo objConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            //string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[Campaign];

            string[] strArray = objCrystalReport.GetCampaignConn();

            CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo();

            objConnInfo.DatabaseName = strArray[1].ToString();
            objConnInfo.UserID = strArray[2].ToString();
            objConnInfo.Password = strArray[3].ToString();
            objConnInfo.ServerName = strArray[0].ToString();

            String ReportPath = (Server.MapPath("Report") + @"\rptInvoice.rpt");

            //String ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~//Report//VendorRegistration.rpt");


            //objReportDoc = objCrystalReport.CrystalLogon(ReportPath, objConnInfo, ref logOnInfo);



            //// for displaying Crystal report

            //crVendorRegistration.ReportSource = objReportDoc;

            //crVendorRegistration.ParameterFieldInfo[0].CurrentValues.Clear();


            ParameterDiscreteValue pdvalue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();


            pdvalue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(sCarrierID);


            //crVendorRegistration.ParameterFieldInfo[0].CurrentValues.Add(pdvalue);

            //crVendorRegistration.DataBind();


            //// for Exporitng in PDF
            ReportDocument repDoc = objCrystalReport.CrystalLogon(ReportPath, objConnInfo, ref logOnInfo);

            repDoc.ParameterFields[0].CurrentValues.Add(pdvalue);




            // Stop buffering the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
            // Clear the response content and headers
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();

            // Export the Report to Response stream in PDF format and file name Customers
            //repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Response, true, "Truck Invoice " + sCarrierID + "");
            //repDoc.GenerateReport


            String ReportGenerated = (Server.MapPath("GenerateReport") + @"\rptInvoice" + sCarrierID + ".pdf");
            // There are other format options available such as Word, Excel, CVS, and HTML in the ExportFormatType Enum given by crystal reports

            ExportOptions CrExportOptions = new ExportOptions();

            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ReportGenerated;

            CrExportOptions = repDoc.ExportOptions;

            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;

            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;

            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;

            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;

            repDoc.Export(CrExportOptions);

            //pdvalue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            //pdvalue.Value = QC_By;

            //crSalesRpt.ParameterFieldInfo[1].CurrentValues.Add(pdvalue);

            //objReportDoc.VerifyDatabase();
            //objReportDoc.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "");

            //if (rethrow)
            //    throw;

            //Redirecting to error message page
            //Server.Transfer(ConstantClass.StrErrorPageURL);
        }
    }
```

by above you create pdf using crystal report by using mail concept u will sending mail thats it