# convert crystal reports into pdf formats

Tags: c#

My report is generated successfully in IIS and now I want to get that report in PDF format. Please guide me - I listed my source below:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
    rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "RAMYA-BD", "");
    rpt.SetParameterValue("MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedItem.Text);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go through following Links:

1. http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4946-Create-pdf-from-crystal-report.aspx
2. http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-pdf.htm

or the stack overflow same problem: [Converting Crystal report to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521702/converting-crystal-report-to-pdf?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you not have add Viewer:

```
Stream st = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"xxx.pdf\"");
st.CopyStream(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Output.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Database connection maybe

```
rep.DataSourceConnections[0].SetLogon("Login","Password");
```

Comment: IF i put this code means it show error like in Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. 
                   Stream st = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

Comment: You remove all line without first. The problem is with the correct set of parameters. The first line is doing the conversion. If you do not do this conversion there can be no export. I don't use SetDatabaseLogon.

Comment: ya u right the first line is not conversion for me that only the problem so what is the solution for this friend....